# Add scale to graphic (esri js)

Tags: javascript, esri, esri-javascript-api

Somebody know how can i add to graphic a scale (a single graphic)?
I have graphics layer and i need for each graphic in it to have a different scale

I have now all the graphic shown in the same scale

I did it by using map.graphics.add()
I used also SimpleSymbol

Thank you

Comment: There are many hundreds of ArcGIS API for JavaScript questions asked and answered at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange but always start with a code snippet to illustrate what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

var polygon = featureSet.features[0].geometry;
     var polygonExtent = polygon.getExtent();

for each graphic in it to have a different scale (get geometry extend and zoom to extend)